# rclone config not listing shared drives for configuration

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, rclone

I am configuring "rclone v1.61.1" in Raspberry Pi Model4 using command rclone config.

After processing the client ID and secret key, its not listing shared drives as shown below:

```
Configure this as a Shared Drive (Team Drive)?

y) Yes
n) No (default)
y/n> Yes
This value must be a single character, one of the following: y, n.
y/n> y

Error: listing Team Drives failed: Get "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?alt=json&pageSize=100&prettyPrint=false": dial tcp 74.135.21.98:443: i/o timeout
Usage:
  rclone config [flags]
  rclone config [command]

Available Commands:
  create      Create a new remote with name, type and options.
  delete      Delete an existing remote.
  disconnect  Disconnects user from remote
  dump        Dump the config file as JSON.
  file        Show path of configuration file in use.
  password    Update password in an existing remote.
  paths       Show paths used for configuration, cache, temp etc.
  providers   List in JSON format all the providers and options.
  reconnect   Re-authenticates user with remote.
  show        Print (decrypted) config file, or the config for a single remote.
  touch       Ensure configuration file exists.
  update      Update options in an existing remote.
  userinfo    Prints info about logged in user of remote.

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for config

Additional help topics:
  rclone config edit       Enter an interactive configuration session.

Use "rclone [command] --help" for more information about a command.
Use "rclone help flags" for to see the global flags.
Use "rclone help backends" for a list of supported services.

2023/06/08 20:52:49 Fatal error: listing Team Drives failed: Get "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?alt=json&pageSize=100&prettyPrint=false": dial tcp 74.125.24.95:443: i/o timeout
```

Appreciate your help to fix the same.

Thank you.